# Deploying Assets to Production using React on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, deployment

I have been able to use Procfile.static and Procfile.hot so my React on Rails is working perfectly in my development environment.  Since there is vert little little documentation for deployment using Puma for React on Rails, I tried to do what I always had been doing to deploy:

```
    RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
    puma
```

However, I get this error right when I run the rake assets:precompile:

```
 andy@railsapp-test:~/production/railsapp$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile 
 cd client && npm run build:production

  railsapp-react@1.0.1 build:production /home/andy/production/railsapp/client
  NODE_ENV=production webpack --https --config webpack.config.js

 Webpack production build for Rails
 Hash: 1c2cf1a47280f63c36ac
 Version: webpack 1.14.0
 Time: 5480ms
             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 webpack-bundle.js  1.53 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
     + 813 hidden modules
 cd client && npm run build:production

 > railsapp-react@1.0.1 build:production /home/andy/production/railsapp/client
 > NODE_ENV=production webpack --https --config webpack.config.js

 Webpack production build for Rails
 Hash: 1c2cf1a47280f63c36ac
 Version: webpack 1.14.0
 Time: 5059ms
             Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
 webpack-bundle.js  1.53 MB       0  [emitted]  main
    [0] multi main 64 bytes {0} [built]
     + 813 hidden modules
 rake aborted!
 Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: app-bundle.
 Load paths:
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/videos
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/webpack
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-sass-rails-4.0.3.0/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-sass-rails-4.0.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/autonumeric-rails-1.9.43/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.14.30/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.14.30/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gmaps4rails-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/simple_calendar-2.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/best_in_place-3.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/best_in_place-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoon-1.2.9/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/videos
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/webpack
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/images
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
   Compass::SpriteImporter
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
 (sass):9
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:347:in `block in _dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `block (2 levels) in each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:194:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `block in each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:346:in `grep'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:346:in `_dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:334:in `dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:36:in `evaluate'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/tilt-2.0.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:99:in `render'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/airbrake-5.7.1/lib/airbrake/rake/task_ext.rb:19:in `execute'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: app-bundle.
 Load paths:
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   CompassRails::SpriteImporter
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/videos
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/webpack
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/casein-5.1.1.5/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-sass-rails-4.0.3.0/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-sass-rails-4.0.3.0/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-ui-rails-4.0.3/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/autonumeric-rails-1.9.43/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.14.30/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails-4.14.30/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gmaps4rails-2.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/simple_calendar-2.1.0/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/best_in_place-3.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/best_in_place-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoon-1.2.9/app/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/images
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/jquery-fileupload-rails-0.4.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/videos
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/webpack
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/javascripts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/fonts
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/images
   /home/andy/production/railsapp/app/assets/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
   Compass::SpriteImporter
   /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.3/assets/stylesheets
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:65:in `import'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:347:in `block in _dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `block (2 levels) in each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:194:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `block in each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/node.rb:195:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:346:in `grep'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:346:in `_dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:334:in `dependencies'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:36:in `evaluate'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/tilt-2.0.2/lib/tilt/template.rb:99:in `render'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:183:in `dfs'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-3.6.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sprockets-rails-3.0.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/airbrake-5.7.1/lib/airbrake/rake/task_ext.rb:19:in `execute'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
 /home/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
 Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So it says something about app-bundle missing? Am I even supposed to be compiling assets like this? Not sure what that means.  Here is my react setup:

```
application.html.erb

  <!-- These do not use turbolinks, so no data-turbolinks-track -->
  <!-- This is to load the hot assets.   -->
  <%= env_javascript_include_tag(hot: ['https://localhost:3500/vendor-bundle.js',
                                       'https://localhost:3500/app-bundle.js']) %>

  <!--Load react on rails hot or static libraries  -->
  <%= env_stylesheet_link_tag(static: 'application_static',
                              hot: 'application_non_webpack',
                              media: 'all',
                              'data-turbolinks-track' => false) %>
```

---

```
package.json
{
  "name": "railsapp-react",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.0",
    "npm": "4.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
     "start": "babel-node server-express.js",
     "build:test": "webpack --https --config webpack.config.js",
     "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --https --config webpack.production.config.js",
     "build:development": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.config.js",
     "hot-assets": "babel-node server-rails-hot.js",
     "build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.rails.build.config.js",
     "build:dev:server": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.server.rails.build.config.js",
     "build:dev:client": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.client.rails.build.config.js"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": ["node_modules", "client/node_modules"],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "loader-utils": "^0.2.16",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.3",
     "axios": "^0.15.2",
     "actioncable": "^5.0.1",
      "classnames": "^2.2.5",
      "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
      "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
      "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
      "babel-polyfill": "^6.20.0",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
      "bootstrap-loader": "^1.3.0",
      "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
      "es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
      "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
      "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
      "immutable": "^3.8.1",
      "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
      "lodash": "^4.17.2",
       "marked": "^0.3.6",
      "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
      "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.4.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
      "react-bootstrap-table": "2.11.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-on-rails": "6.5.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
      "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "1.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0"



  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^2.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^3.10.2",
    "eslint-config-shakacode": "^13.2.0-beta.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.7.1",
    "estraverse-fb": "^1.3.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jsdom": "^9.8.3",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.1",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.4",
    "sleep": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  }
}
```

---

```
webpack.production.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nodeEnv = devBuild ? 'development' : 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
  //  './app/bundles/dashboard/startup/registration',
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: '../app/assets/webpack',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve('./node_modules/react-dom'),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv),
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        loader: 'imports?shim=es5-shim/es5-shim&sham=es5-shim/es5-sham',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
  );
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

Im assuming there has to be some other way to compile assets just using the React package and serve them some weird way in my application.html.erb maybe ? I really don't even know what to try at this point!

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!! Now the assets compile great and puma serves them properly.   I had to set my package.json "scripts" like this :

```
     "scripts": {
     "start": "babel-node server-express.js",
     "build:test": "webpack --https --config webpack.config.js",
     "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --https --config webpack.client.rails.build.config.js",
     "build:development": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.config.js",
     "hot-assets": "babel-node server-rails-hot.js",
     "build:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.rails.build.config.js",
     "build:dev:server": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.server.rails.build.config.js",
     "build:dev:client": "webpack -w --https --config webpack.client.rails.build.config.js"
  },
```

Then I had to add the following to application.html.erb so the static js would load in:

```
 <!-- These do use turbolinks -->
<%= env_javascript_include_tag(static: 'application_static',
                             hot: 'application_non_webpack',
                              'data-turbolinks-track' => false) %>
```

Now im just having an issue with Jquery not being loaded (or not being loaded first) but im so glad to be over that mountain!